# how to remove already defined pending intent

Tags: android

I have problem with alarm manager pending intent.
I have read in document that 
**Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent resolution (filtering). That is, if their action, data, type, class, and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data included in the intents.
Parameters**

And **set method of alarm manager will remove or replace If there is already an alarm for this Intent scheduled (with the equality of two intents being defined by filterEquals(Intent)).**

But when I implement using same concept my alarm manager will not filter equal intent and prevent to add same data to pending intent.

My code is

```
public void setalarm() {
    int[] IDs = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int[] type = { 0, 1, 0 };
    String[] name = { "not", "yes", "not" };
    Date[] dt = { new Date(2012, 2, 28, 11, 51),
            new Date(2012, 2, 29, 10, 55), new Date(2012, 2, 28, 11, 51) };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent send = new Intent(context, service.class);
        send.setAction("com.app.main");
        send.setData(Uri.parse(type[i] + " " + name[i] + " " + dt[i]));
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, IDs[i],
                send, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                        | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        try {
            am.cancel(pintent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dt[i].getTime(), pintent);
    }
}
```

When alarm call service on start method, it will call two times from id 1 as well as 3.
but I have setdata same in id=1 and id=3;

but user can only set alarm for id =1 not for 3 because 1st and 3rd are same

Answer (score 15):

Rewrite the code in CancelAlarm() function

```
 PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, IDs[i], 
                send, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT 
                        | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

With The `Same Intent send and Same Id IDs[i]` and then Cancel that `pintent` like this,

```
pintent.cancel();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just recreate the same PendingIntent (with the same extras) and use the cancel method

> If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of
>   PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories,
>   and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent
>   representing the same token if that is still valid, and can thus call
>   cancel() to remove it.

Example:

```
am.cancel(pintent)
```